# Remove the data where certain words come

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called "companynames" which consist of about 9000 company names. I want to remove those company names from the data where these certain words come like

```
stopwords <- c("Trade","Investment","Trading")
```

Comment: Use `df1[!df1$companynames %in% stopwords,, drop = FALSE]`  If it is not an exact match, then use `grep` i.e. `df1[!grepl(paste(stopwords, collapse="|"), df1$companynames),]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply use the `filter` function from `dplyr` package along with the `grepl` function.

```
stopwords <- c("Trade","Investment","Trading")

stopwords <- paste(stopwords,collapse = "|")

df %>% filter(!grepl(stopwords,companynames))
```